# How to add draggable functionality after listener

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

So I am trying to avoid JQUERY UI or really any libraries JS wise and am trying to create some drag and drop functionality in backbone.JS. I've already been able to have some success as you can see at www.smartkrawl.com on the left side but cannot get tables to move in the canvas section. Here is a snippet of code that listens for a mousedown event to execute a draggable function but if you view the source code of the site the JS files, particularly ocoa-tables.js, are available. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

```
    var Table = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize:function(options){
        this.set("x",options.x);
        this.set("y",options.y);
        this.set("el",options.el);
        $('body').on('mousedown','.table', function() {
            console.log('mousedown')
        });

    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably should use view for this instead of model. So make each table as a separate view, then use `events` hash to add listeners instead of delegating it on the `body`

```
var TableView = Backbone.View.extend({

    events: {
        "mousedown": "_onMouseDown"
    },

    _onMouseDown: function(e) {
        console.log('mousedown')
    }
});

var firstTable = new TableView({ el: ".first.table" });
var secondTable = new TableView({ el: ".second.table" });
```

Comment: I get the whole event listener thing and I may switch that up it's more of a matter of, okay, I have this table in the canvas area now, how do I move it like I did in the leftpane?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with backbone.js though I do feel like I have a decent grasp on jQuery. I hope I'm not asking an obvious question, though if it's the table that you want, why not directly target the table?

```
$(".table").on("mousedown", function() {
...
});
```

Comment: I get the whole event listener thing and I may switch that up it's more of a matter of, okay, I have this table in the canvas area now, how do I move it like I did in the leftpane?